# Adding custom ttf font excludes numbers

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add a custom font to my project, but it keeps excluding the numbers. I downloaded Nunito font from google. Am I missing something?

*NOTE:* Numbers still appear when you use the fonts in a label, but they do not show in Finder Preview or the when you open them in Xcode.

Xcode version 10.1 (10B61), swift 3

.ttf file in xcode

[image]

.ttf file when I open on mac

[image]

Comment: No idea why viewing the font in Xcode isn't showing the number chars, but they*are* there. Quick test with "Nunito-SemiBold.ttf" and "Nunito-Regular.ttf" and no problem putting "ABC123" in a label.

Comment: @DonMag so your numbers aren't showing in the ttf files, but they _are_ showing in a label? I'm using them in a label as well and my numbers are not changing. (Tested with 1... there should be an underline on the bottom)

Comment: They ***are NOT*** showing in Xcode's *default display* when the font is selected in the Navigator pane. The numbers ***are*** showing when I use them in a label.

Comment: Here's a cap, using `theLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Nunito-SemiBold", size: 48)` ... https://imgur.com/a/Oq71zEX

Comment: I forgot to add the font family in my plist. So the numbers _DO_ work, but they are not displayed in the default display.

Comment: Worth noting... the numbers do not display in Finder Preview either.